# JQuery Mobile JSON call displays blank page

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am developing a website using Jquery Mobile and JSON Call, it shows the loading model, but it goes to blank page after that.

I am using JQuery mobile 1.9.1

Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    private ActionResult Accept(ProcessPaymentRequest request, string errorPage)
    {
            return Json(apiRequest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HMTL:

```
<div class="container" data-ajax="false">
<div class="modal hide automodal" id="processModal">
    <div class="modal-body box-loading">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 5%;"></div>
        </div>
        <h2>Please wait a while...</h2>
        <p>We are processing your payment.</p>
    </div>

    <form action="" method="post" id="processForm123">   
        <input id="OneTwoThreeReq" name="OneTwoThreeReq" type="hidden" value="">             
    </form>  

    <form action="" method="post" id="newCCprocessForm">  
        <input name="paymentRequest" id="paymentRequest" type="hidden" value="">   
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">        

         var interval = 5;
         setInterval("loadProgress();", 1000); //every 2s
         function loadProgress() {
             if (interval >= 100) {
             }
             else {
                 interval += 5;
                 $('.bar').width(interval + '%');
             }

         }

    </script>  

</div>
```

i found out that instead of goes out to this page:
2C2PFrontend/UAT/TestClient/Index.asp

it show this page with this html:

```
<head></head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
    <div class="ui-page ui-body-c" data-role="page" data-url="/2C2PFrontend/UAT/PaymentV3UI/Payment/MAccept" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 634px;"></div>
    <div class="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"></div>
    <div class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="/2C2PFrontend/UAT/TestClient/Index.aspx" data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 284px;">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="centered"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Kindly any one know how to prevent this happened?

i am create my own loading box as show in HTML code above and below in the function that i use to called it:
        function ShowLoadingDialog() {

```
    //console.log("ShowLoadingDialog");

    $('.bar').width("5%");
    if (interval > 5) interval = 0;
    if ($('.overlay').length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    }
    $('.overlay').show();
    $("#loadingModal").toggle(100);

}
```

and below is my AJAX call

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Accept",
                data: $('#credit_card_details_form').serialize(),
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.encrypted_payment_request != "") {
                        $("#newCCprocessForm #paymentRequest").val(msg.encrypted_payment_request);
                        $("#newCCprocessForm").attr('action', msg.processUrl);
                        $("#newCCprocessForm").submit();
                    } else {
                        //window.location.href = "Error?result=" + msg.result + "&result_desc=" + msg.result_desc;
                        window.location.href = "CCResult";
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.location.href = "Error";
```

it's a bit messy, since i am just continue a project that was left by other developer.

Comment: are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: actually i found out the cause, jquery mobile is adding additional html, so i doesn't process the request, how to disable it? please see above

Comment: does it show you progress bar for a moment and everything disappears?

Comment: yes, it is like what you mentioned

Comment: are you calling $.mobile.changePage() function to load your page with progress bar?

Comment: hi, please see my addition above, do i suppose to use that one to load my page or how?

Comment: let me rephrase my question. have you at any point used JQM function $.mobile.changePage() to change between pages? I am asking this because the function is known to cause the anomaly that you are facing right now.

Comment: no, i don't use it at all

Comment: Hi, it's solved, i just add target="_self" to my link, very strange